# How Do I Download Facebook Images Using cURL?

Tags: php, facebook, curl, web-scraping

I have a PHP script that works just fine downloading most remote images to my file system, but when I try to download a Facebook or Instagram image I get an error that says "failed to open stream: No error in" followed by the line of my fopen function and two additional errors "fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in" which is obviously due to the Facebook image not downloading.

My code is as follows:

````
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.facebook.com/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)');
$page = curl_exec($curl);
if(curl_errno($curl)):
    echo 'Erro: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
endif;
curl_close($curl);
// Use basename() function to return the base name of file
$file_name = basename($url);
if(file_exists($file_name)){
    unlink($file_name);
}
$fp = fopen($file_name,'x');
fwrite($fp, $page);
fclose($fp);```

There also seems to be an error when I try to add the first line of code to this post which is:

```$url = 'https://scontent-sea1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p180x540/119041795_176402070632464_6192328410277888324_o.jpg?_nc_cat=111&ccb=2&_nc_sid=825194&_nc_ohc=O7khk9mGFO4AX86nd5X&_nc_ht=scontent-sea1-1.xx&tp=6&oh=ff35f5eaf960fa7bd30ab1d549f0d817&oe=6045A0D1';```
````

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, you have to use the graph api

Comment: Using the graph api is not an option for me, so I need to either find a way to make this curl script work or use a screenshot API. If there is a way to make curl work please let me know.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow scraping.

Comment: Facebook has some measures in place to try and prevent such unauthorized access. Plus, cURL-ing `https://www.facebook.com/` likely would not achieve too much even if it did work - most of the content is loaded via JavaScript requests in the background. You’d need a _headless browser_ to execute any JS as well, to emulate what is actually going on when the site loads. But, if Facebook figures out that you are doing this from a static (server) IP, don’t be surprised if they simply block it at some point.

Comment: I have run some tests using a screenshot API with Instagram images and those tests have been successful. I simply give the screenshot API the URL of the image, it takes a screenshot of the image, and saves the screenshot to the file system.

Comment: Cbroe, good point about the IP. My remote server has a static IP so they probably would do that, but I also have XAMPP and NordVPN on my PC. I could probably configure the server to allow me to post remotely and then setup a scheduled task on my PC to run the script via XAMPP. Then if my IP gets banned I can just change it via NordVPN.

Answer (score -1):

Screenshot APIs are the workaround for this. There are many, but to spare the one I am using from any scrutiny for how it is being used by now I will not name the specific program. Most are basically the same, but you should choose one that allows you to install it on your own system rather than being dependent on simply getting a screenshot from a URL of theirs. That way you can encode the Facebook/Instagram image URL that you want to take a screenshot of, send the encoded URL to the API, and save the result on your file system.

The ability to encode the URL is key because of all the query strings in Facebook/Instagram image URLs.